# Accessing chrome devtools protocol in docker grid

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

My tests are running against a docker grid with selenium docker images for hub and chrome. What I am trying to do is access chrome devtools protocols in the chrome node so that I can access/intercept a request.Any help is appreciated

I was able to get it working without docker in my local. But could not figure out a way to connect the devtools in chrome node of docker grid. Below is my docker-compose and code

docker compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  selenium_hub_ix:
    container_name: selenium_hub_ix
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    environment:
      SE_OPTS: "-port 4445"
    ports:
      - 4445:4445
  chrome_ix:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest
    container_name: chrome_node_ix
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub_ix
    ports:
      - 5905:5900
      - 5903:5555
      - 9222:9222
    environment:
      - no_proxy=localhost
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium_hub_ix
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4445
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
      - TZ=America/Chicago
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

Here is sample code  how I got it working in local without grid (chrome driver in my mac)

```js
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
let webDriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
module.exports = {
async openBrowser() {
this.driver = await new webDriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
            let session = await this.driver.session_
            let debuggerAddress = await session.caps_.map_.get("goog:chromeOptions").debuggerAddress;
            let AddressString = debuggerAddress.split(":");
            console.log(AddressString)
            try {
                const protocol = await CDP({
                    port: AddressString[1]
                });

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.message)

                const {

                    Network,
                    Fetch
                } = protocol;

                await Fetch.enable({
                    patterns: [{
                        urlPattern: "*",
                    }]
                });

            }
            await Fetch.requestPaused(async ({
                interceptionId,
                request
            }) => {
                console.log(request)

            })
        }
        return this.driver;
    },
}
```

When it is grid, I just change the way build the driver to below

```js
 this.driver = await new webDriver.Builder().usingServer(process.env.SELENIUM_HUB_IP).withCapabilities(webDriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
```

With that I am getting the port number but could not create a CDP session and I get a connection refused error.